# Delete data from GPS unit using Garmin Communicator Plugin API

Tags: javascript, garmin

I'm building a project that relies heavily on data read from a bunch Garmin eTrex HC devices, to do that I use the [Garmin Communicator Plugin API](http://developer.garmin.com/web-device/garmin-communicator-plugin/), I have successfully found the device, read the data and uploaded it to a server where I will do further data manipulation.

However, I now want to delete the data I have read from the device, I have found nothing in the [API reference](http://developer.garmin.com/web/communicator-api/jsdoc/symbols/Garmin.Device.html) provided by Garmin and now, I need to turn to you clever folks in order to solve my problem since I've been tearing my hair out all morning trying to figure this out.

I cannot rely on the person carrying the device to reset it properly since there is an  angle of competition in the mix.

Any way I can delete the data from the device will be greatly appreciated, any solution that involves, deleting data, resetting the device or really, whatever.

If the community answer is "This cannot be done" I will have to accept that and do some fact checking on the server side (which I might do anyways) in order to prevent data uploaded multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like garmin simply hasn't included this natively into the API, but...

When you delete data you're actually writing data.

It doesn't look like the JS file GarminDevice.js has any method for removing data. I would write zeros or otherwise into the data space.